# how to return multiple column of result in a row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables in a database.

Table **T1**:

```
ID    TeamLeader
---   -----------
1     Iron Man
2     Thor
3     Hulk
```

Table **T2**:

```
TeamID   Member
------   ------
1        Superman
1        Spiderman
2        Batman
2        Catwomen
2        Robin
3        Black Widow
3        Hawk Eye
3        Captain America
```

I would like to have a `SELECT` statement that return as below.

```
TeamID  TeamLeader  Member
------  ----------  ------
1       Iron Man    Superman;Spiderman;
2       Thor        Batman;Catwomen;Robin;
3       Hulk        Black Widow; Hawk Eye;Captain America;
```

I tried to create a function that uses temporary table, but it says i can't use temporary table in a function.

Please help.

Comment: See link :  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/

Comment: You can also use COALESCE .. Refer : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/06/sql-server-creating-comma-separate-values-list-from-table-udf-sp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
     ID, TeamLeader,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ';' + [Member]
          FROM Table2
          WHERE TeamID = a.ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS MembersList
FROM Table1 AS a
GROUP BY ID, TeamLeader
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b1fa/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ TEAMLEADER ║             MEMBERSLIST              ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Iron Man   ║ Superman;Spiderman                   ║
║  2 ║ Thor       ║ Batman;Catwomen;Robin                ║
║  3 ║ Hulk       ║ Black Widow;Hawk Eye;Captain America ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*extra `;` at the end*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b1fa/5)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ TEAMLEADER ║               MEMBERSLIST               ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Iron Man   ║ Superman; Spiderman;                    ║
║  2 ║ Thor       ║ Batman; Catwomen; Robin;                ║
║  3 ║ Hulk       ║ Black Widow; Hawk Eye; Captain America; ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with `STUFF` to do this. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.teamleader,
  STUFF((
    SELECT '; ' + t2.member  
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.teamId = t1.id
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Members
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.Id, 
         t1.teamLeader;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb4a1/2)

This will give you:

```
| ID | TEAMLEADER |                                MEMBERS |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |   Iron Man |                    Superman; Spiderman |
|  2 |       Thor |                Batman; Catwomen; Robin |
|  3 |       Hulk | Black Widow; Hawk Eye; Captain America |
```